# In While Statement, to get increased variable out of the while statement

Tags: java

```
package src;

public class Ball {
    public static int bounceBall(double h, double bounce, double window) { 
        int n = 0;
        double result; 
        result = Math.pow(bounce,n);
        int p;
        
        if((h>0) && (0<bounce && bounce<1) && (window < h)) {
            n=1;
            p=1;
            
            while(result*h>window) {
                n++;
                p++;
            }
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

In this code, how can i get increased p out of while statement and return?
(and is my code grammatically right?)

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Can you be a little more clear please

Comment: while(result*h>window) {
                n++;
                p++;
            }
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }
        return p;                 at this part, can i return value of p(while statement applied)? and the location of "return p;" is gramatically right?

Comment: Yes, if your `while` condition is `true` your `p` will get incremented.

Comment: you have to change at least one of result, h, or window for the results of the while check to change

Comment: You have `result = Math.pow(bounce,n);` with **n=0**. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: mm when i compile it, it sads Math.pow needs initialized variable.. so i have no choice but initialize variable n anyway.

Comment: @doko you can simply initialize `result` with `1`. (better for readability).

Comment: The body of the `while` loop is not updating any variables `result`, `h`, or `window`. Therefore, the `while` loop will either not run entirely (because the condition is `false`) or will run always (the condition will always be `true`).

Comment: Thank you so much! but can you explain me more easily? why while loop is not updating any variables? i can get result, h by test methods ( not in this code, i have test file.) when i run this code, All result appears to be "p = 1"